# How to make Visual Studio IntelliSense to not automatically complete a word, do this only by TAB key?

Tags: visual-studio, autocomplete, visual-studio-2017, intellisense

Sometimes IntelliSense behavior is very annoying.
For example, typing in c# editor "Random[SPACE]" resulted "Random3DDataGenerator" in my code when the is no "using System;" in the code. I had to press [CTRL]+[Z] to return back the "Random" word.

In earlier versions of VS there was an option which said after which characters auto-completion is applied, but now it seems there is no such option.

Is there some ways to avoid this annoying behavior?

Comment: there used to be a way in Visual Studio to set the set of keys which will trigger a completion, which I *loved*.. but I can't find it right now.. i don't know if that is because it's buried, or because it has been removed.

Comment: Yes, they removed it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just switch off auto completion mode using the settting: Edit->Intellisense->Toggle Completion Mode

You can see more information here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hcw1s69b.aspx

"You can also change to suggestion mode, in which only the text you type is inserted into the code."

Comment: This works in SSMS as well (something I wish I knew 15 years ago)

Comment: Is asking how to change the completion key config, not how to disable the functionality entirely and change for a similar one.
:)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, ctrl+alt+space toogles between suggestion mode and standard completion mode. In suggestion mode what you type is part of options you can use.